# I am unable to send messages from twilio API using nodejs sdk from a US number to a UAE number

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms, voice

I am unable to send SMS message from a US twilio number to a UAE  twilio number.
Also in the geographical settings, sending SMS to UAE numbers is enabled.

I am pasting code here:

```
const accountSid = '<account-sid>';
const authToken = '<auth-token>';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.m
  .create({
     body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
     from: '<us-number>', // example: +12345678901  country code is +1
      to: '<uae-number>' // example: '+971123456789' country code is +971 (also i tried different uae numbers, didn't work)
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid)).catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

I am getting error text: `Message cannot be sent with the current combination of 'To' (+97112345XXXX) and/or 'From' (+12345678901) parameters`

But if I hit the twilio voice call api with the same `from` and `to` parameters, it works like a charm. See example below:

```
   client.calls
   .create({
     twiml: '<Response><Say>Hello, this is a test voice call from Twilio.</Say></Response>',
     from: '<us-number>', // same us number
     to: '<uae-number>',  // same uae number,
   })
   .then(call => console.log(`Call SID: ${call.sid}`))
   .catch(error => console.error(`Error making voice call: ${error.message}`));
```

It will successfully return a call sid.

I am pretty clueless what's wrong with the message here, anyone faced a similar issue there, meanwhile I have sent support to twilio and waiting for their reply since hours!

Answer (score 0):

Got solution from twilio support, I have to register alphanumeric sender ID for UAE: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046382293-Documents-Required-and-Instructions-to-Register-Your-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-in-UAE